# Symfony 4 - Some difficults with Cascade={'persist','remove'}

Tags: php, doctrine, entity, symfony4, cascade

and sorry for my English, I'm French so I use a translator.
Here is a part of my model to illustrate my words:

[image]

So that's the trouble. I am in my Admin Settings page. On this page I will be able to add / delete holiday types.
But when I delete types of holidays, it would have to delete things cascading in the database.

In fact the principle of the site is the following:

Users ask for their holidays. For that they give the type of leave for which they will be absent. And for each type of holiday, users have a balance.

So I have this:

**ParametresAdmin.php:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeConge", mappedBy="parametresAdmin", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $typesConges;
```

**TypeConge.php:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $nom;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Absence", mappedBy="typeConge", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $absences;
```

**SoldeConges.php:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeConge", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $typeConge;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="soldeConges")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", nullable=true)
 */
private $solde;
```

**Absence.php:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="absences")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $user;
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\TypeConge", inversedBy="absences")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $typeConge;
```

**User.php:**

```
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\SoldeConges", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER", cascade={"remove"})
     */
    private $soldeConges;
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Absence", mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $absences;
```

So, in my admin settings, if I delete a type of leave, it must follow this pattern:

- Suppression of absences related to the type of leave.
- Removal of the 'soldeUser' from User, for balances that are related to the type of leave.
- Suppression of the 'typeConge' (type of holiday)

But whith my code, I've this error when I try to delete a type of holiday :

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM type_conge WHERE id
>   = ?' with params [9]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`congestest2`.`solde_conges`, CONSTRAINT `FK_BE0A8BDB753BDA5` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`type_conge_id`) REFERENCES `type_conge` (`id`))

Comment: Do you set the `$typeConge` property of all `SoldeConges` instances to `null` where the `TypeConge` instance being removed was associated before?

Comment: Mmh sorry I don't understand what you mean :/

Comment: Just triggering a remove of a certain `TypeConge` instance will not be enough as there are still `SoldeConges` entries referencing the one that you remove. You will have to make sure to clear this association first.

Comment: Yes, I see, but I don't see how can I delete these ```SoldeConges``` before